# remove bootstrap glyphicons from bootstrap css

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, webpack, sass, glyphicons

I want to remove Bootstrap icon pack from the Bootstraop css because it is too heavy and I am using font awesome. Is there any way to remove it.

I am using web pack to compile scss files to css.

I am using the latest version of bootstrap. I have installed `bootstrap-sass` and `@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";` to import bootstrap.

If you require any further information please comment.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? And are you referencing the Bootstrap CSS directly or building it from source?

Comment: [Bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) create you custom scss file in whitch you import bootstrap-sass component that you want to use and don't import `_glyphicons.scss`

Comment: @DavidG I have updated my question

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz that's exactly what I wanted to know. Can you answer this question with the code also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In stead of importing the `bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap`
just create a custom file in whitch you import evrything without glyphicon like this

Content of the `bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap` is like this and I put some modification on the line where glyphicon is import

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "bootstrap/variables";
@import "bootstrap/mixins";

// Reset and dependencies
@import "bootstrap/normalize";
@import "bootstrap/print";

// Here is where the glyphicons are import
// I comment just this line and every thing will work like you want without the glyphicons
//@import "bootstrap/glyphicons"; 

// Core CSS
@import "bootstrap/scaffolding";
@import "bootstrap/type";
@import "bootstrap/code";
@import "bootstrap/grid";
@import "bootstrap/tables";
@import "bootstrap/forms";
@import "bootstrap/buttons";

// Components
@import "bootstrap/component-animations";
@import "bootstrap/dropdowns";
@import "bootstrap/button-groups";
@import "bootstrap/input-groups";
@import "bootstrap/navs";
@import "bootstrap/navbar";
@import "bootstrap/breadcrumbs";
@import "bootstrap/pagination";
@import "bootstrap/pager";
@import "bootstrap/labels";
@import "bootstrap/badges";
@import "bootstrap/jumbotron";
@import "bootstrap/thumbnails";
@import "bootstrap/alerts";
@import "bootstrap/progress-bars";
@import "bootstrap/media";
@import "bootstrap/list-group";
@import "bootstrap/panels";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-embed";
@import "bootstrap/wells";
@import "bootstrap/close";

// Components w/ JavaScript
@import "bootstrap/modals";
@import "bootstrap/tooltip";
@import "bootstrap/popovers";
@import "bootstrap/carousel";

// Utility classes
@import "bootstrap/utilities";
@import "bootstrap/responsive-utilities";
```

```

Comment: Is this same for bootstrap version 4 and above? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: you are welcome for bootstrap 4 there isn't glyphicon component, look at here [Bootstrap 4 asset](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/v4-dev/scss) and the file that import all assert is the [bootstrap.scss](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss)

Comment: So, you mean there are no glyphicon in Bootstrap 4? I have not started using Bootstrap 4 yet.

Comment: Yes, they have decide to remove it from bootstrap and the suggest to use glyphicons as an external component or fontawesome  [Drop the glyphicons font](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that. Thanks for your help. Happy coding. 